# get ref once all descendants are finished rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref, react-leaflet

I'm working on a react-leaflet custom control, and I have a component whose ref I need.  But this component has dynamically rendered children.  Something like this:

```js
<LayersControl ref={controlRef => this.controlRef = controlRef}>
  {this.props.children}
</LayersControl>
```

The children have their own children as well.  As these children are rendered, they affect the underlying leaflet logic.

(For those not familiar, or curious, `LayersControl` will create an [L.control.layers](https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/).  The children of the `LayersControl` will always be a `LayersControl.BaseLayer` or `LayersConrol.Overlay`.  Those will then have children, which could be any number of not-yet-known react-leaflet layers or components.  As the `.BaseLayer` or `.Overlay` components mount, they modify the underlying `L.control.layers` object.)

I am trying to get a reference to the leaflet instance of the component *after all descendants have rendered*.  However, calling the `ref` function as I've called above, that's not what happens.  While my ref is indeed defined in the `componentDidMount`, it is incomplete.  For example, some of the crucial properties that I need from within `cdm` are not yet available (i.e. the `._container` property).

I know that his is how refs are intended to work - they give you a ref as soon as the root element has rendered and mounted, even if the children and descendants have not yet mounted.  Short of doing some hack like doing a `setTimeout` and getting the ref after `10ms`, **how can I get a ref of this element once all descendants are done rendering?**

### [Working demo of the issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/leaflet-controls-5yk59)

Comment: `<LayersControl />` needs to provide an `onLayersReady()` callback. I've worked with data-grids libraries that provide that functionality. Kinda basic if you ask me. So yes, I suppose the only solution, hackish as it may seem, is to wrap it in a `setTimeout`

Comment: Would you mind elaborating?  I've never heard of an `onLayersReady()` function, and I'm not seeing it anywhere in the leaflet or react-leaflet docs. Where would such a function be placed, what would it do, and how would it relate to my ref and cdm?

Comment: No no, sorry for being unclear. I'm saying that the library SHOULD provide that `API` callback, instead of letting consumers of the component deal with this issue

Comment: Welp, if you checked out the example codesandbox, you may have noticed that I'm in the process of rebuilding those components anyway.  And react-leaflet v3 is currently in the beta testing stage.  So now would be a great time to write a callback like that.  Any idea how that can be accomplished?  (perhaps that brings us back to my original question?) Or shall I head over the react-leaflet v3 repo and put in an issue / feature request?

Comment: I'm not too certain but how ag-grid and other grid libs do is to notify the callback once all the code is initialized. I suppose if you know how many components are to be loaded, then you will be able to know once all components are loaded. However, code may be ready but the `DOM` might not be. So you will also need to ensure that they are in sync somehow.